# How to enable a trace with scpi commands

Tags: automation

I am using SCPI commands to program a Tektronix TTR506A Vector Network Analyzer, and I need to have 2 traces enabled at once. The system preset is to have just one trace, so I need to find a command that will enable the second trace. I have looked at the programmers manual to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will be under the display commands. First you will need to assign the active graph then assign the trace to the graph.

This will be on page 2-15 of the programmer manual:
https://www.tek.com/vna/ttr500-manual-5